# Sending push messages without an app

Tags: php, push-notification

I am a PHP developer and work with a small team of ~20 real estate agents.
Lately there's a need for some server-to-person notifications (real time notifications, otherwise I could have used email for this).

There could be around 20-30 messages/day/person, mostly on iOS, but also a few androids.

So I've been looking at push notifications, which seem to do the trick, but all services I found (parse.com, for instance) seems to be for android developers (they need an app).
I'm not an Android developer, and creating an app for this would probably take me too much time.

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this with a simple API?

I considered SMS at first (clickatell api), but the boss wants a free service (or a flat charge).
Thank you for your advice!

[Update] - seems that I did not explain the situation correctly, I apologize for that
I'm looking for a (maybe free) service that has it's own app in Google Play and Apple Appstore and will allow me, as a PHP programmer, to send push notifications in near realtime to any of the ~20 devices in my organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably looking for http://app.net/

you can download apps for iOS and Android from here: https://app.net/mobile/

ask every user's to install this on phone.(so that you can send push notifications to them)

The easiest way to send a broadcast with the API is via the ADNPy Python module, the adn Ruby gem, the appnet.js library for Node.js, or the AppDotNetPHP library. You can also use the HTTP API with your own client, if you’d like.

please find PHP library for the App.net Stream API here: https://github.com/jdolitsky/AppDotNetPHP

for broadcast see this code from same github: https://github.com/jdolitsky/AppDotNetPHP/blob/master/recipe-example/send-broadcast.php

from their help topics:

> Broadcast Channels are designed to carry low-volume, high-value
>   updates of interest to users. We call the actual updates themselves
>   Broadcast Messages (or sometimes just “broadcasts”). Because
>   broadcasts are built on top of the existing App.net Channel and
>   Message APIs, it’s helpful to be familiar with them, but for simple
>   tasks, there’s not much you need to know.
>
> Just a reminder: while you can do all of this using our API, you don’t
>   have to. We have tools for publishers to help you quickly get started
>   pulling content in from elsewhere on the web, **and you can send them
>   manually via the web or the App.net iOS and Android apps**. To get
>   started, we recommend that you create and set up your broadcast
>   channel with our web publisher tools and only use the API to send
>   broadcasts via the channel you created.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: forgive me. 

  but tropo's PHP API integration doc is very lengthy, can't copy paste here.

Comment: Just paste the relevant parts.

Comment: alright, I'm editing my answer to add essentials parts. (can't add in comments since more than 150 characters)

Comment: thanks, but as I was saying, we rather use push and not SMS.
there must be a service out there that allows this, maybe they have their own app for receiving the push-ed messages?

Comment: I never heard of app.net, but it does look promising.
I will check it out today.
Thank you!

Comment: always welcome, Catalin!

Comment: ended up using pushover and pushbullet, but app.net seems interesting also.